# Не работают спецификаторы %c и %d в printf после ввода символа

Tags: c, кодировка, visual-studio-2017

Какой бы символ я не вводил вместо символа и его ASCII-кода VS17 выводит вот что:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/fKiAv81.png]

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <conio.h>
  int main(void)
    {
        char ch;
        printf("Enter any character:\n");
        scanf_s("%c", &ch);
        printf("The code for the character %c is %d.\n ", ch, ch);
        _getch();
    }
```

Comment: Никакого отношения к `printf` проблема не имеет. Если уж вы взялись использовать `scanf_s`, то хоть документацию удосужьтесь почитать.

Comment: При использовании scanf выводит error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Comment: Это не отменяет того, что вы должны прочитать документацию про scanf_s

Comment: @Vladislav Dubnic: Это совсем не означает, что вы можете просто заменить имя функции со `scanf` на `scanf_s` и больше ничего не делать. `scanf` и `scanf_s` - две совершенно разные функции и используются они по-разному.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VС++ 2017. Если плюнуть на предупреждение о недостатке аргументов в `scanf_s`:

```
G:\Tmp>test.exe
Enter any character:
G
The code for the character G is 71.

G:\Tmp>test.exe
Enter any character:
V
The code for the character V is 86.
```

Вы точно ничего не скрываете? :)

Попробуйте явно указать все параметры `scanf_s`: `scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);` - так вы указываете, что принимающий буфер имеет размер 1 символ (т.е. вы гарантируете, что по указанному адресу `&ch` можно безопасно записать 1 символ).

Comment: Точно.Может ли это быть как-то связано с тем что сам код находится в "Файлах ресурсов"?

Comment: Попробуйте еще явно указать все параметры [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx): `scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);`

Comment: Это решило проблему,большое спасибо) Вот только не могли бы Вы в двух словах описать что именно делает эта единица?Гугление пока не помогает

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.